# Why apache directory studio not supported for latest Java versions?

Tags: apache-directory

I was using my apache directory studio till morning and unfortunately updated the java version in my laptop to latest version. From the time I updated my Java version Apache directory studio stopped to work.

When I check Apache Directory Studio site

http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/1.3-installing-and-starting.html

it was mentioned that Java 7.0 as prerequisite. I dont have the software for Java 7 currently as I upgraded it. Please let me know why is such an ignorance from Apache directory studio to work with only older version and not with newer versions of Java

Answer (score 1):

Apache Directory Studio does work well with Java 8.

If you installed Java 9, you will have a trouble starting Studio. It's documented on the site, and there is a workaround :

http://directory.apache.org/studio/faqs.html#error-when-using-java-9

Answer (score 1):

To run Apache Directory Studio on Java Version 9:

Add this line `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` to `ApacheDirectoryStudio.ini`.

In windows, this file is located in `C:\Program Files\Apache Directory Studio\`